# Aerodynamic Physics

Tags: unity, c#, physics

The current unity physics engine is limiting in the sense of drag. It's just not good enough. After a lot of internet sailing... I found this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716989/unity-aircraft-physics/49727704#49727704

I used this guys code and found that it works although with the very slight problem that needs to be addressed. The aircraft gains energy when it makes turns making it incredibly hard to control and land. While linear drag effects are as given, desirable. The angular drag seems to be almost negative? Which seems to give it an increase in speed. I unfortunately havent had time to test this and this kind of flight physics is a bit of learning curve for me to understand. So could someone help me out to see why there is a extreme gain in energy while turning?

```cs
        public Rigidbody Rb;
        //public GameObject airFlow; No need to consider here
        public int numEngines;
        public float engineThrust;
        private float throttle = 0;
        //private float dragCoeff = 5f; No need to consider
        //public float liftCoeff = 0f; No need to consider
        private float airDensity = 1.2f;
        private float crossSectionalArea = 1;
        public float wingSpan = 0;
        public float wingArea = 0;
        public float forceMultiplier = 1; //Used to boost engine performance
        private Rigidbody rigid;

        private void Awake()
        {
            rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            Rb.drag = Mathf.Epsilon;
            //if (controller == null)
                Debug.LogError(name + ": Plane - Missing reference to MouseFlightController!");
        }


        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                Mathf.Lerp(throttle, throttle + 1, Time.deltaTime);
                throttle += 1 /** Time.deltaTime*/;

                throttle = Mathf.Clamp(throttle, 0, 100);
                throttleUI.text = throttle + "%";
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
            {
                Mathf.Lerp(throttle, throttle - 1, Time.deltaTime);
                throttle -= 1 /** Time.deltaTime*/;
                throttle = Mathf.Clamp(throttle, 0, 100);
                throttleUI.text = throttle + "%";
            }
         }

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            //Rb.drag = CalculateDrag();
            //Rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.back * CalculateDrag());
           // Rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * CalculateLift(), ForceMode.Force);
            rigid.AddRelativeTorque(new Vector3(turnTorque.x * pitch,
                                        turnTorque.y * yaw,
                                        -turnTorque.z * roll) * forceMult,
                            ForceMode.Force);
            ApplyThrust();
            inducedPhysics();
        }

        void ApplyThrust()
        {
            float Thrust = engineThrust * numEngines * (throttle / 100);

            Debug.Log("Thrust: " + Thrust);
            Rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * (Thrust * forceMultiplier), ForceMode.Force);
        }

        void inducedPhysics()
        {
            var localVelocity = transform.InverseTransformDirection(Rb.velocity);
            var AoA = Mathf.Atan2(localVelocity.y, localVelocity.z);
            float aspectRatio = (wingSpan*wingSpan)/wingArea;
            float inducedLift = AoA * (aspectRatio / (aspectRatio + 2f)) * 2f * Mathf.PI;
            float inducedDrag = (inducedLift * inducedLift) / (aspectRatio * Mathf.PI);
            float pressure = Rb.velocity.sqrMagnitude * 1.2754f * .5f * wingArea;
            float lift = inducedLift * pressure;
            float drag = (0.021f + inducedDrag) * pressure;
            Vector3 dragDirection = -Rb.velocity.normalized;
            Vector3 liftDirection = Vector3.Cross(dragDirection, transform.right);
            Rb.AddForce((liftDirection * lift) - (dragDirection * drag));
        }
```

TLDR; The code calculates its drag forces and uses mathematical approximations for drag and lift. Help is much appreciated if any.